# Get a reference to a Highcharts chart

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I render a Highcharts chart in a div with id `container` like so:

```
new Highcharts.Chart({
    chart: {
        renderTo: 'container',
        type: 'line',
        zoomType: 'x'
    },

    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Jan', 'Feb']
    },

    series: [{
        data: [29.9, 71.5]
    }]
});
```

```html
<div id="container" class="chart"></div>
```

Notice that I haven't captured a reference to the chart object in a variable. At some point after the chart has been rendered is it possible to get a reference to the chart object from the ID of the element it has been rendered to (`container` in this case)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With jQuery

```
var Mychart=$("#container").data('highchartsChart');
```

or

```
var Mychart=$("#container").highcharts();
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/members/axis-setcategories/)

---

or via the Highcharts' charts array ([0] if your chart is the first)

```
var Mychart = Highcharts.charts[0];
```

Answer (score 2):

You can access it through the Highcharts object. Every chart created with Highcharts will be pushed into Highcharts' `charts` array. If this is the first chart you've created, you can get a reference to it like so:

```
var chart = Highcharts.charts[0];
```

Your element itself will contain a reference to the index of the above array within it's `dataset` property. Again, if this is the first chart you've created, you'd see something like the following:

```
document.getElementById('container').dataset;

> DOMStringMap { highchartsChart: "0" }
```

This `highchartsChart` property holds the relevant array index, which you can then use to ensure you have the correct chart selected:

```
var index = document.getElementById('container').dataset.highchartsChart,
    chart = Highcharts.charts[index];
```

Comment: `Highcharts.chart[0]` causes this error `TypeError: Highcharts.chart is undefined`

Comment: @Dónal sorry that's a typo, `chart` should be `charts`: `Highcharts.charts[0]`. I've altered my answer.